# Why am I getting 255 for all NPK values?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, esp8266, nodemcu, iot

I am using a NodeMCU ESP8266 WiFi board for collecting N - P - K sensor data. I am using RS485 as interface.

This is the code:

```C
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    
    #define RE D6
    #define DE D7
    
    #define RO D0
    #define DI D1
    
    const byte nitro[] = {0x01,0x03, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x00, 0x01, 0xe4, 0x0c};
    const byte phos[] = {0x01,0x03, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x01, 0xb5, 0xcc};
    const byte pota[] = {0x01,0x03, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x01, 0x85, 0xc0};
     
    
    
    byte values[11];
    SoftwareSerial mod(RO , DI); //R0 and DI
    
    void setup(){
    
    
      pinMode(RE, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(DE, OUTPUT);
     
      // put RS-485 into receive mode
      digitalWrite(DE, LOW);
      digitalWrite(RE, LOW);
    
    
      Serial.begin(9600); 
      mod.begin(9600);
     
      Serial.println("Code started");
    
      byte nitrogen_value = nitrogen(); //N value
      delay(1000);
    
      byte phosphorous_value = phosphorous(); //P value
      delay(1000);
    
      byte pottasium_value = potassium(); // K value
      delay(1000);
    
      
      Serial.println("Values are:");
      Serial.println(nitrogen_value);
      Serial.println(phosphorous_value);
      Serial.println(pottasium_value);
    
    }
    
    void loop(){
    
    }
    
     byte nitrogen(){
    
      digitalWrite(DE,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(RE,HIGH);
      
      delay(1000);
      
      if(mod.write(nitro,sizeof(nitro))==8){
        
        digitalWrite(DE,LOW);
        digitalWrite(RE,LOW);
    
    Serial.print("Executing Nitrogen");
        for(byte i=0;i<7;i++){
      
        
        values[i] = mod.read();
        
        Serial.print(values[i],HEX);
        }
        Serial.println();
      }
      return values[4];
    }
      
    byte phosphorous(){
      
      digitalWrite(DE,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(RE,HIGH);
      
      delay(1000);
      
      if(mod.write(phos,sizeof(phos))==8){
        
      
        digitalWrite(DE,LOW);
        digitalWrite(RE,LOW);
        
        for(byte i=0;i<7;i++){
        
        
    
        values[i] = mod.read();
    
        Serial.print("Executing Phosporous");
        
        Serial.print(values[i],HEX);
        }
        Serial.println();
      }
      return values[4];
    }
      
    byte potassium(){
      
      digitalWrite(DE,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(RE,HIGH);
    
      delay(1000);
      
      if(mod.write(pota,sizeof(pota))==8){
         Serial.print("Executing pottasium");
    
        digitalWrite(DE,LOW);
        digitalWrite(RE,LOW);
        
        for(byte i=0;i<7;i++){
    
       
        
        values[i] = mod.read();
        Serial.print(values[i],HEX);
    
        }
        Serial.println();
      }
      return values[4];
    }
```

During execution I always get 255 as output

[image]

Please help me to find the mistake and error.

Comment: What precisely does this mean --> *N - P - K sensor's data*? What is the sensor and where can its data sheet be found?

Comment: We'd also need to know how the software serial is implemented. Do you know how it works? Sounds like Arduino code so you may have better luck in Arduino.SE, if this is not cleary an Electronics question.

Comment: @Andyaka NPK soil sensor.Here is the link : [link] (https://www.google.com/search?q=soil+npk+sensor&rlz=1C1YTUH_enIN1036IN1036&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVvrT8vKH9AhUdcGwGHQaPDmMQ_AUoAnoECAIQBA&biw=1360&bih=693&dpr=1.41#imgrc=DSR9329NKeI3VM)

Comment: Please provide a **definitive** data sheet link. Put that link in your question i.e. edit your question with this information.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry I don't understand you !! But this is a reference link : [link] (https://lastminuteengineers.com/soil-npk-sensor-arduino-tutorial/)

Comment: A data sheet is a revision controlled pdf document that details all the interface requirements for a product, IC or sensor. Links to web-sites are not revision controlled and can change thus invalidating any information taken from them when making an answer on this site.

Comment: The code seems to be copied from a tutorial. Therefore, the problem may be in hardware. Or this hardware is not compatible with the code if it is meant for other hardware.

Comment: Seems you are using software serial with the hardware uart0, gpio1 and gpio3. Suggest you change that. Lots of tutorials on both.

Comment: @DrG Sorry for late reply. Could you please explain bit more I didn't get what you said.

Comment: @Steve54 My comment was cryptic, sorry. - Seems like you are using  #define RO D0   #define DI D1 with software serial  SoftwareSerial mod(RO , DI); //R0 and DI right?  When I look at the pinouts for your board https://components101.com/development-boards/nodemcu-esp8266-pinout-features-and-datasheet D0 is for Flash and D2 is TX2 and you are using those for Software Serial. I would try using hardware serial or different GPIO for software serial...unless I am missing something.